# disable w3c validation in specific divs

Tags: html, validation

is there a way to run a webpage through https://validator.w3.org/ while also ensuring that a particular div's contents will not be checked?

On a certain page, I print an email that was **scraped** from gmail and display it exactly how it was obtained from gmail. I would like to be able to validate all the html code around that email itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it's not possible to validate partial content in the page.
With regards to your specific case you may have two solutions.

1. Just validate the template with a dummy content in pre-production stage.
2. insert the email in a programmatic way through an iframe